# Azure AD B2C integration with external IDP using OpenID Connect in Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm integrating with an external IDPs using OpenID Connect. I've referred to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-openid-connect?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)

The configuration is working fine for the first IDP (external Azure AD tenant) and i'm able to sign-in successfully.

However, for the second IDP, i'm getting an error when I click on the sign-in button on the login page. Instead of re-directing to the login page of the IDP, i'm gettng an error page. After looking at application insights, i'm seeing the below error:

```
{"Kind": "FatalException","Content": {"Time": "1:59 AM","Exception": {"Kind": "Handled","HResult": "80131500","Message": "The jwk key can't be deserialized. Reason: 'Certificate key and key object are not identical'.","Data": {"IsPolicySpecificError": false}}}}
```

Here is the technical profile defined for the IDP that is throwing the error:

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="IDP2-OpenIdConnect">
          <DisplayName>SSO OpenID</DisplayName>
          <Description>Login using OpenID Connect</Description>
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="METADATA">https://<base URL removed>/api/oauth2/v2/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
            <Item Key="client_id"><client_id removed></Item>
            <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">openid</Item>
            <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>            
            <Item Key="ClaimTypeOnWhichToEnable">identityProviders</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimValueOnWhichToEnable">idp2openid</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="EMAIL" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="FIRST_NAME" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="LAST_NAME" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="EMAIL" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />          
          <EnabledForUserJourneys>OnItemExistenceInStringCollectionClaim</EnabledForUserJourneys>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

The technical profile is identical to the technical profile of IDP1 which is working (except for the URLs, client id etc.). Any insights into what the issue could be is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the CryptographicKeys entry?

What do your claims exchanges look like?

Look at this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/default-home-realm-discovery) for how to handle multiple domains and EnabledForUserJourneys.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Since the response_type in the technical profile of idp2 is id_token (not code), a client secret is not required. This same technical profile configuration is working for a different IDP (IDP1).

EnabledForUserJourneys is working I am able to show/hide sign-in button for the IDP based on the claim passed to the B2C policy. The issue occurs when I click on the button. Instead of redirecting me to the IDP2 login page, I get the error mentioned in the original post. Looks like B2C is doing some sort of validation before constructing the redirect URL?